# React resizable only resizing the width of the box, not the height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a [React-mui draggable dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/) component on which I am using [resizable box](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resizable):

```js
return (
  <StyledDialog
    open={open}
    classes={{root: classes.dialog, paper: classes.paper}}
    PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
    aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog"
  >
    <ResizableBox
      height={520}
      width={370}
      minConstraints={[300, 500]}
      maxConstraints={[Infinity, Infinity]}
      className={classes.resizable}
    >
      <DialogContent classes={{root: classes.dialogContent}} id="draggable-dialog">
        <IconButton className={classes.clearIcon} aria-label="Clear" onClick={onClose}>
          <ClearIcon/>
        </IconButton>
        <iframe
          src={hjelpemiddel.url}
          title={hjelpemiddel.navn}
          width="100%"
          height="100%">
        </iframe>
      </DialogContent>
    </ResizableBox>
  </StyledDialog>
);
```

I would like to resize the `iframe` inside the dialog along with the `ResizableBox`. But, it seems I can only resize the width of the `ResizableBox`, and not the height of the box, at least the maximum height seems to be the one that is set initially. How can I fix that, so that I can resize the height as well?

**UPDATE**

Codesanbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feynman-gybve?file=/src/PDFDialog.js).

FYI, for some reason sometimes import fail message appears, but everything works fine if you refresh the page of the codesandbox.

Comment: I would provide more details, based on https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-automatically-resize-an-iframe-7be6bfbb1214, I would try `width:100%;border:none;` in iframe style.

Comment: The problem is with the resizable box not the iframe. I can't seem to resize the box by it's height.

Comment: Could you create a sandbox so that it'll be easier to help you? https://codesandbox.io/s/new Also, your dialog styles matter

Comment: You could provide the resizable class in the question, there might be something there that is blocking the override of the height

Comment: I have added the codesandbox to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CodeSandBox, based on my testing, the events for dragging & resizing are simultaneously firing. You could use the [`cancel`](https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable#draggable-api) prop of `react-draggable` so that the dragging would not occur when the resize handle is the component being interacted with.

```
<Draggable
  cancel={".react-resizable-handle"}
    ...
```

When you do this, the draggable element will not be updating its CSS `transform: translate` property anymore while resizing - for this, you can opt to control your Draggable component's position. Translate/Set X & Y as necessary to retain its position while resizing. Note that the `x` & `y` state & state setters should be residing on a common parent/ancestor among these components that you will be passing down as props.

```
export default function App() {
  // have the source of truth for the positions on a common parent/ancestor
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PDFDialog x={x} y={y} setX={setX} setY={setY} />
    </div>
  );
}

...

class PDFDialog extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <StyledDialog
        open={open}
        classes={{ root: classes.dialog, paper: classes.paper }}
        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog"
        PaperProps={{
          x: this.props.x,
          y: this.props.y,
          setX: this.props.setX,
          setY: this.props.setY
        }}
      >
        <ResizableBox
          height={520}
          width={370}
          minConstraints={[300, 500]}
          maxConstraints={[Infinity, Infinity]}
          className={classes.resizable}
          onResize={(e) => {
            if (e.movementX !== 0) {
              this.props.setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
            } else if (e.movementY !== 0) {
              this.props.setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY / 2);
            }
          }}
        ></ResizableBox>

        ...

// refactored draggable component:
<Draggable
  position={{ x: x, y: y }}
  cancel={".react-resizable-handle"} // <-- cancel the dragging if resize is interacted with
  onDrag={(e) => {
    if (e.movementX !== 0) {
      setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
    }
    if (e.movementY !== 0) {
      setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY);
    }
  }}
>
  <Paper {...props} />
</Draggable>
```

[image: Edit React MUI + Draggable + Resizable Component]

(On my CodeSandBox, I've gotten rid of constraints such as minimum `height` & `width` to clearly show the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the event of resize of window, calculate the new height and width and pass it to the `resizable-box` of yours

```
object.addEventListener("resize", function() {
//Here you can write logic to apply resizing on the resizable-box
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `react-resizable` uses inline CSS to handle *width* and *height* of a box, and for your issue, I simulate this issue, pay attention to the below screenshot from Google chrome devTools:

[image]

The `react-resizable-box` has an *important* flag and it overwrites the inline height value so in the view, I have the following behavior:

[image: motion]

Your information is not enough so I cannot say directly your issue cause or causes but it is very probable CSS overwriting is the root cause of this issue.

So, inspect the `resizable-box` on your project and seek to find CSS overwriting.

## Update after adding re-produce the issue

Actually, based on my last answer something overwrite your `height` now in the re-production sandbox, I delete the `iframe` tag, and everything works well, you pass a `height="100%"` attribute to your `iframe` tag and it prevents the change of height. Also, you pass a `minConstraints={[300, 500]}` to your `ResizableBox` component, so it could not have a smaller height than `500px`.

Comment: I have added the codesandbox with my example to the question.